# Is there a way to return multiple columns with XLOOKUP within an ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm using `XLOOKUP` to return a row with 4 columns. At the moment I have to copy/paste the formula every time new rows are inserted, so I thought of using `ARRAYFORMULA` to skip this step.

The problem is when I implement this, the result is a single column per row instead of the 4 columns I get by having a `XLOOKUP` per row; The result seems to be trimmed to only the first column.

My `XLOOKUP` looks something like this:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!D2:G)
```

And applying `ARRAYFORMULA` this is how it looks:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!D2:G))
```

Any ideas on how can I make it return the full 4 columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map()`, like this:

```
=map(A2:A, lambda(a, xlookup(a, Sheet2!A2:A, Sheet2!D2:G)))
```

See
[map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) and
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718).

Answer (score 3):

Further to doubleunary's answer, the reason why `xlookup` doesn't work in the expected way with `arrayformula` is because, as per the documentation: '*If result_range is more than one row or column, then the output will be the entire row/column at the index a match was found in the lookup_range*', i.e. it returns an array by default, so the desired arrayformula result would be an array-of-arrays which isn't supported by arrayformula. Doubleunary's answer is effectively generating an array-of-arrays using `map` which does allow this.

You could also try `=arrayformula(vlookup(A2:A,{Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!D2:G},{2,3,4,5},0))` which works because vlookup does not return arrays by default so arrayformula works on both the *search_key* and *index* arguments to return a contiguous 2D array (which is allowed).